# Does MKL contain phase shift functionality? (like 'unwrap' in MATLAB)

Tags: intel-mkl, phase

Is there any phase shift functionality implemented in MKL? (the equivalent of the 'unwrap' function in MATLAB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MKL doesn't support such functionality